# Problema con Carbon y fecha en string

Tags: laravel, datetime, carbon

El problema es que me indica este error
`DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (17/07/2019) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character`

Vista en mi formulario tengo por separado el input de fecha y hora, pero con carbon los quiero juntar y guardarlos en un solo campo.

utilizo Bootstrap 4 y TempusDominus

```
<div class="col-5 col-xl-5">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group date" name="event_start_date" id="event_start_date" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" name="event_start_date" required="" id="event_start_date" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#event_start_date" placeholder="Fecha de inicio"/>
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#event_start_date" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
              <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-4 col-xl-5" id="event_start_time_area" style="display: none">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group date" id="event_start_time" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" name="event_start_time" id="event_start_time" value="00:00" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#event_start_time" placeholder="Hora de inicio"/>
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#event_start_time" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
              <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock"></i></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

el error hace referencia directa a la linea `$dataTimeFecha_i = new Carbon($fecha_i);` de mi controlador

intente de esta forma `$dataTimeFecha_i = new DateTime($fecha_i);`, pero me sale el mismo error

```
$fecha_i= $request['event_start_date'];
$dataTimeFecha_i = new Carbon($fecha_i);
$hora_inicio = $request['event_start_time'];
$fecha_hora_inicio = Carbon::instance($dataTimeFecha_i)->setTimeFromTimeString($hora_inicio)->toIso8601String();
```

Este es la configuracion de mi script referente a el formato de Tempus Dominus

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
  $('#event_start_date').datetimepicker({ 
    locale: 'es',
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    minDate: "now",
    pickTime: false
  });
  $('#event_end_date').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'es',
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    minDate: "now",
    pickTime: false
  });
  $('#event_start_time').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'es',
    format: 'LT'
  });
  $('#event_end_time').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'es',
    format: 'LT'
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbon puede reconocer algunos [formatos comunes](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-commonformats) , pero para un string como `$fecha_i = "17/07/2019"` no podrá reconocerlo sin que se lo especifiques. Puedes usar [`createFromFormat`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-conversion), pasándole el formato correcto:

```php
$dataTimeFecha_i = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fecha_i);
```

Comment: Si funciono!!, Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Debes de parsear el fecha:

```
$fecha_i= $request['event_start_date'];
$dataTimeFecha_i = Carbon::parse($fecha_i);
```

Con eso debería de quedar.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, lo intente como me indicas, pero aun me sale el mismo error `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (17/07/2019) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character`

Comment: @KilzaNiko, intenta hacer un dd($fecha_i); y mustra su resultado, como foto.

Comment: Me funciono con la respuesta de @porloscerros Ψ, muchas gracias igual por la ayuda.